# Deberia usar innerhtml o nodevalue?

Tags: javascript

deberia usar innerhtml o nodevlue para cambiar un elemento ?, veo que los dos obtienen el mismo resultado y en mi opinion innerhtml es mucho mas simple, deberia utilizar este ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun el user @jtbandes del sitio de ingles:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760126/how-do-i-choose-between-innertext-or-nodevalue

haciendo referencia al articulo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Using_Web_Standards_in_your_Web_Pages/Using_the_W3C_DOM:

> Si el elemento no tiene subelementos, solo texto, entonces
>   (normalmente) tiene un nodo secundario, al que se accede como
>   ElemRef.childNodes [0]. En tal caso preciso, el estándar de estándares
>   web W3C de ElemRef.innerText es ElemRef.childNodes [0] .nodeValue.

Comment: osea que podria usar innerhtml en de texto ? y en que caso no seria texto ? .-. gracias

Comment: @Pachi se refiere cuando tiene varios o solo un hijo, si es solo un hijo seria childNode[0]

Comment: entonces si tiene hijos no deberia usar innerhtml correcto ?

Comment: @Pachi asi es, es como un acceso directo para no no acceder al arreglo childNode[0] ademas que tiene fea sintaxis

Comment: okey y si tiene hijos deberia usar node, pero si le asigno una id/clase a dicho hijo podria seguir usando innerhtml verdad? gracias

Comment: claro pero tambien podrias usar nodeValue que practicamente son lo mismo, solo es por cuestiones de sintaxis

Comment: ok gracias, creo que me quedare con innerhmtl si puedo lograr lo mismo, lo veo mas simple ;D